# How to confirm how many files downloaded with mget?

Tags: unix, sftp

So what's the simplest way to check if sftp / mget actually pulls a file or not?

My current script looks like this:

```
  sftp  ${SFTP_USER}@${SFTP_SERVER} <<EOF 
     cd ${SFTP_SOURCE_DIR}
     mget ${FILEPATTERN}* ${AL_FTP_DIR}
     bye 
  EOF
```

But during testing, if there is no file matching the file pattern, no error is returned, and the script carries on blissfully unaware.

Assuming I could already have files in the current directory of matching ${FILEPATTERN}* ... how can I tell if the mget actually pulled anything?

My best thought for a solution would be to use a temporary directory ... check and move ... *shrug* .. but I'm thinking there has to be a more elegant solution?

```
  TDIR="AL_TMP_$$"
  mkdir $TDIR

  sftp  ${SFTP_USER}@${SFTP_SERVER} <<EOF 
     cd ${SFTP_SOURCE_DIR}
     mget ${FILEPATTERN}* ${AL_FTP_DIR}/${TDIR}
     bye 
  EOF

  CHKCNT=`ls -ltr $TDIR | wc -l`

  if [ ${CHKCNT} -eq 1 ];
  then
     echo "ERROR: No files found on FTP server."
     rmdir $TDIR
     exit 1
  fi
  mv $TDIR/* .
  rmdir $TDIR
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
# count files before transfer
files=( "$AL_FTP_DIR"/* )
n_before=${#files[@]}

# transfer
sftp ...

# count files after transfer
files=( "$AL_FTP_DIR"/* )
n_after=${#files[@]}

diff=$((n_after - n_before))
echo "$diff files were transferred"
```

Comment: hmm, I had initially dismissed that due to parallel jobs running, however, as I think about it more, yeah, this would work, the parallel jobs work on different file patterns :)  So I could use this trick ... I guess that saves the temp directory ...   Thanks!